# JQM, Android 2.3, password input field incorrect overlay

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile

Android 2.3 version. App developed with jQuery mobile and phonegap. Why password input field behaves so strange? White input field border overlays in incorrect position.

[image: password input field border overlay]

HTML code:

```
<div data-role="content" class="loginContent">
        <div id="loginLogoContent">
            <div id="loginLogo">
                <img src="../../css/images/ivo.png" style="vertical-align:middle" />
            </div>          
            <div class="logoText">xxx</div>
        </div>

        <div>
            <form id="loginForm">   
                <input type="text" id="card" placeholder="xxx" class="required">                
                <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="yyy" class="required">

                <label for="remember_login">xxx</label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="remember_login" id="remember_login">               

                <input id="loginButton" type="submit" name="login_submit" value="yyy">              
            </form>

            <input id="registerButton" type="button" name="register" value="xxx" class="registerButton">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What version of jQuery and jQuery Mobile are you using?

Comment: can you provide the whole of index.html (or whatever is the file that is being loaded)? it could be possible the viewport header is causing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

sorry, can't reproduce your problem, see screenshot (HTC Desire, Android 2.2, Dolphin browser), which looks fine...

[image]

Comment: It seems to me that you tried to reproduce an error in a browser. Is that correct? An error appears only in a real device which runs on Android 2.x version.

Comment: A browser and a WebView are two different things. Typically, with jQM, apps are created in a WebView object and do not run in a full-fledged browser. So, just because it is running fine in Dolphin browser does not really help.